# Default constructor not found for type Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I've been developing an app for `iOS` using `MvvmCross` locally for a while without issue and this morning I proceeded to publish onto my iPhone 5S. The app fails on launch stating:

```
Default constructor not found for type Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector
```

I'm using `MvvmCross 3.1.1` from `NuGet` in `Xamarin Studio`.

Halfway through the development I upgraded the binaries from `MvvmCross 3.0.5`.

I cant get into debugging it as when the error is thrown it kills the app on the phone and the debugger before I can follow the trail!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you upgrade all plugins to 3.1.1? I've seen problems when using mismatched versions.

Comment: All plugins were updated to 3.1.1, so I rebuilt the project and copied across my classes from the old project and it worked. Looking at the diff in mercurial the only glaring difference was the omission of `[MonoTouch.Foundation.Preserve (AllMembers = true)]` in the linker file. Its working again now.

Comment: @CFrancis, I am facing same problem. But I cannot find linker file. Where is the linker file?